# Reading symmetrical Harwell-Boeing matrix in Python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, eigenvalue, finite-element-analysis

SciPy can read only read unsymmetric matrices with hb_read.  Anyone know if it is possible to read symmetric matrices in Python (3)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using BeBOP Sparse Matrix Converter to convert to MarketMatrix and then importing this into Python.